# jMonkeyEngine: lwjgl.dll (Access is denied)

Tags: java, file, dll, sdk, jmonkeyengine

I'm trying to compile a jMonkeyEngine project I made a while back.  But when I compile I get a message saying "lwjgl.dll (Access is denied)."  I have looked online for some help but found nothing.

FYI:
I'm using an AMD A6 64-bit CPU with Windows 8.

Stacktrace:

```
Sep 18, 2014 7:30:33 PM com.jme3.system.JmeDesktopSystem initialize
INFO: Running on jMonkeyEngine 3.0.0 Beta
Sep 18, 2014 7:30:33 PM com.jme3.system.Natives extractNativeLibs
INFO: Extraction Directory: E:\JME\jMonkeyEngine 3.0\Lab11
Sep 18, 2014 7:30:33 PM com.jme3.system.JmeDesktopSystem initialize
SEVERE: Error while copying native libraries
java.io.FileNotFoundException:  E:\JME\jMonkeyEngine 3.0\Lab11\lwjgl.dll (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at com.jme3.system.Natives.extractNativeLib(Natives.java:170)
    at com.jme3.system.Natives.extractNativeLib(Natives.java:113)
    at com.jme3.system.Natives.extractNativeLibs(Natives.java:265)
    at com.jme3.system.JmeDesktopSystem.initialize(JmeDesktopSystem.java:309)
    at com.jme3.system.JmeDesktopSystem.newContext(JmeDesktopSystem.java:228)
    at com.jme3.system.JmeSystem.newContext(JmeSystem.java:128)
    at com.jme3.app.Application.start(Application.java:387)
    at com.jme3.app.Application.start(Application.java:368)
    at com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication.start(SimpleApplication.java:130)
    at lab11.Lab11.main(Lab11.java:105)

Sep 18, 2014 7:30:34 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay run
INFO: Using LWJGL 2.8.4
Sep 18, 2014 7:30:34 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglDisplay createContext
INFO: Selected display mode: 500 x 500 x 0 @0Hz
Sep 18, 2014 7:30:37 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: Adapter: aticfx64
Sep 18, 2014 7:30:37 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: Driver Version: null
Sep 18, 2014 7:30:37 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: Vendor: ATI Technologies Inc.
Sep 18, 2014 7:30:37 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: OpenGL Version: 4.2.12198 Compatibility Profile Context 12.102.1.1000
Sep 18, 2014 7:30:37 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: Renderer: AMD Radeon HD 8280G
Sep 18, 2014 7:30:37 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: GLSL Ver: 4.20
Sep 18, 2014 7:30:37 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglTimer <init>
INFO: Timer resolution: 1,000 ticks per second
Sep 18, 2014 7:30:37 PM com.jme3.renderer.lwjgl.LwjglRenderer initialize
INFO: Caps: [FrameBuffer, FrameBufferMRT, FrameBufferMultisample, TextureMultisample, OpenGL20, OpenGL21, OpenGL30, OpenGL31, OpenGL32, ARBprogram, GLSL100, GLSL110, GLSL120, GLSL130, GLSL140, GLSL150, VertexTextureFetch, TextureArray, TextureBuffer, FloatTexture, FloatColorBuffer, FloatDepthBuffer, PackedFloatTexture, SharedExponentTexture, PackedFloatColorBuffer, TextureCompressionLATC, NonPowerOfTwoTextures, MeshInstancing, VertexBufferArray, Multisample, PackedDepthStencilBuffer]
Sep 18, 2014 7:30:37 PM com.jme3.asset.AssetConfig loadText
WARNING: Cannot find loader com.jme3.scene.plugins.blender.BlenderModelLoader
Sep 18, 2014 7:30:37 PM com.jme3.asset.DesktopAssetManager <init>
INFO: DesktopAssetManager created.
Sep 18, 2014 7:30:38 PM com.jme3.renderer.Camera <init>
INFO: Camera created (W: 500, H: 500)
Sep 18, 2014 7:30:38 PM com.jme3.renderer.Camera <init>
INFO: Camera created (W: 500, H: 500)
Sep 18, 2014 7:30:38 PM com.jme3.input.lwjgl.LwjglMouseInput initialize
INFO: Mouse created.
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Turns out jMonkey was not recognizing my project's assets folder.  So I decided to create a new JME project from scratch & copied my code to the new project.  Runs perfectly now.